# show/hide boxes based on saved value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a home page that displays a bunch of tiled boxes and a link to an options page that will allow my users to hide or show any one of those boxes and then save those settings.

Here is what i have so far:
    
    Options Page

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#musicHide").click(function(){
        $("#mymusic").hide();
      });
      $("#musicShow").click(function(){
        $("#mymusic").show();
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<p>My Music</p>
<input type="radio" id="musicHide" value="0"/>Hide
<input type="radio" id="musicShow" value="1" checked="checked"/>Show
</body>
```

Home Page:

```
<div class="items">
<a id="mymusic" class="box" href="#" style="background: #F8591A;">
<span>Music</span>
<img height="150px" width="150px" class="icon" src="images/my-music.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Here is one problem that I currently have:
When I click on the hide radio button the 'Show' radio button does not unselect.

- How do I do this?

When I use the options page it does not update the home page.

- Is this possible?
- Do I have to have the code on the home page and not on a different page (options page)
- Should I use a side menu on the home page instead?

Also, I want to store these values per user by them hitting a save button so the next time they open the page it remembers what they wanted to show and hide.

Comment: `$('element').removeAttr('checked');` ??

Comment: You can store the users' selections in a cookie or in localStorage and then automatically populate the options based on their settings by reading the cookie/localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set up your radio buttons the way you want, you'll need to add the same Name attribute to each element.
e.g:

```
<input type="radio" id="musicHide" value="0" name="radioMusic"/>Hide
<input type="radio" id="musicShow" value="1" checked="checked" name="radioMusic"/>Show
```

In order to persist the "Options" to the Home Page, you will need to store the preferences somehow. This will most likely be a database of some kind, but you can also use cookies for temporary storage.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How do I send the values to the database using PHP? Should open a new question?

Comment: I would suggest you do some research on databases first. You have to understand the difference between front-end/UI, and back-end data storage, as a basic programming concept. 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relational-databases-for-dummies--net-30244

You'll need to install and configure a database management system (DBMS) of some kind on the server. Popular database software includes Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server,  MySQL, NoSQL, and many more. 

Once you've configured your database, you'll need to be able to issue commands to your database using Structured Query Language (SQL).